# Deleting objects in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4

I've got a serious problem with Entity Framework 4.0 with deleting objects.

I would like to have a possibility on my client to create MyObject with all children connected to it and then operate on it. I mean add children, remove children and so on, and when I finish working with that simply save it on my Context.

Then I would like to get it from my Context, add something, remove something and than save it again.

Does selfTracking enables this?

I am already not able to do it :/ I invoke startTracking and so on, but each time I Apply changes on the context it wants to add everything as new object. Thanks for any hint.

Comment: It could help if you posted your code, so that we can see exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Check with Following code,

```
            object originalItem;
            EntityKey key = ObjectContext.CreateEntityKey(entityName, entity);
            if (ObjectContext.TryGetObjectByKey(key, out originalItem)) {
                ObjectContext.ApplyCurrentValues(key.EntitySetName, entity);
            }
            ObjectContext.SaveChanges();
```